# How to retrieve MySQL database data using a php search bar

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a search bar using PHP and I want to retrieve the data I have in my MySQL database.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search'];

if(!$button)
echo "You searched for '<b>$search</b>' <hr size='1'</br>";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "PM_DB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE $construct";
$run = mysqli_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "There are no results for <b>'$search'</b>. Please check your spelling.";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

while($runrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$Company = $runrows['Clients'];

echo "<a href='$Company'><b>Company</b></a><br>";

}
}

?>
```

Every time I click search it only returns the error message. What am I missing out? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated! Thanks - Tijger.

Comment: provide the error message

Comment: does it give error or prints that no results were found?? Also, `$x` has not been initialized anywhere before the loop.

Comment: It prints that no results were found, and ok, could it be that because     $x hasn't been initialised outside of the loop that it isn't returning anything?

Comment: Once place OR operator Instead of AND in $construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);

$construct = "SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE keywords LIKE ";
$construct .= "'%".implode("%' OR '%", $search_exploded)."%'";

$run = mysqli_query($construct);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/XxaHAh)

Comment: That only returns "SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE keywords LIKE %company%There are no results for 'company'. Please check your spelling."

Comment: see the updated answer ... I forgot the Single Quotes .... 

Just use the above code now

Comment: It's still only returning "There are no results for 'company'. Please check your spelling."

Comment: Replace `AND` with `OR`

Comment: Try it now ... I changed the position of single quote ... copy the code from answer now

Comment: Still getting the same thing, I've searched absolutely everywhere for a solution to this and can't find a thing anywhere.

Comment: `$run = mysqli_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());`

This will tell if query was run succesfull or not

Comment: It's returning absolutely nothing now, just a blank page.

Comment: Please paste your current code http://ideone.com/ here

And share link with me ... I will do that for you

Comment: http://ideone.com/VOp5Ob - That's all the code with all of the changes, how it currently is.

Comment: @Tijger see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

As I requested the code from OP

I commented the two lines which were causing error for him

He was executing the right query and then the wrong query again ... that is why getting no results returned.

```
<?php
        $button = $_GET ['submit'];
        $search = $_GET ['search'];

        if (!$button)
            echo "You searched for '<b>$Search</b>' <hr size='1'</br>";
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "PM_DB");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);

        $construct = "SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE keywords LIKE ";
        $construct .= "'%" . implode("%' OR '%", $search_exploded) . "%'";

        $run = mysqli_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());

        // Why thisssssssssssssssssss??????????? OMG
        //$construct = "SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE $construct";
        //$run = mysqli_query($construct);

        $foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($run) or die(mysql_error());

        if ($foundnum == 0)
            echo "There are no results for <b>'$search'</b>. Please check your spelling.";
        else {
            echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

            while ($runrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                $Company = $runrows['Clients'];

                echo "<a href='$Company'><b>Company</b></a><br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Still returning a blank page.

Comment: Hmm I dont know but maybe You are having some error maybe.
add 
`error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your PHP code and see if there is any error

Comment: I've added that line and it's still returning a blank page with no errors reported.

Comment: That's ok, thanks for trying though, I appreciate it.